# Understanding method invocation in Scala

Tags: scala, method-invocation

I'm pretty new to `Scala` and came from `Java` and got confused by some piece of code when reading [***this documentation***](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/introduction.html#Routing_DSL_for_HTTP_servers). Here is the code.

```
val route =
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
```

Where `path("hello")` is the method of trait:

```
trait PathDirectives /*extends omitted*/ {

    def path[L](pm: PathMatcher[L]): Directive[L] = pathPrefix(pm ~ PathEnd)
   // the rest omitted
}
```

So, when we invoke the `path("hello")` method we would need an object implementing the trait to invoke it on. But in the example it was just a method invocation. Just like a static method.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, when we invoke the path("hello") method we would need an object implementing the trait to invoke it on.

Yes, and that object is `akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives`. The reason that you don't need to write `Directives.path` is that the code imports `Directives._`, so you can call `Directives`' methods directly (similar to a static import in Java except the method doesn't have to be static).